# How to add Interval in Interstitial Ads using “expo-ads-admob”

Tags: react-native, admob, expo

I am using Expo for developing the ReactNative app, and added interstitial Ads from "expo-ads-admob" in it. I want to show the Interstitial Ad after every 60 secs. But it is showing a single Ad just after opening it and then no Ad. Please help me out with this.

```js
import {
  AdMobInterstitial,setTestDeviceIDAsync
} from 'expo-ads-admob';

export default class App extends Component {

 
  async componentDidMount(){
    await setTestDeviceIDAsync('EMULATOR');
      AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-6726786803906385/1416335240'); 
      await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true});
     
      await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
     
   
    
  }

  render() {
    return (        
         
------------------
            
       
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after so much  trial I got an answer for this problem and I want to share that with you guys;

```js
import {
  AdMobInterstitial,setTestDeviceIDAsync
} from 'expo-ads-admob';

export default class App extends Component {

 
  async componentDidMount(){
    await setTestDeviceIDAsync('EMULATOR');
      AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); 
      await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true});
     await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
    
    
     const that = this;
     setTimeout(() => {
     // write your functions    
     that.componentDidMount();
   },60000);
    }
  


  render() {
    return (
    ---------
    ---------
    --------
    --------
       
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a bit of an old answer, but you may want to clean this up by creating a separate function named something like `showInterstitial()` to call initially in `componentDidMount` and then instead of calling `componentDidMount()` in a `setTimeout()` function, you could call your `showInterstitial()` in a `setInterval()` function. This will free up your `componentDidMount` function should you need to add additional logic there in addition to it being more readable and predictable in the long run.